# PyQt Multi Threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt

Hi I am trying to make small piece of application and have only a few ideas about threading, I can do simple stuffs to with threading but cannot understand the concepts of "QThread".

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QThread
import sys
import src.backend as backend

class oGUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, title, width, height):
        // few code removed
        // few code removed

        self.timer3 = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer3.timeout.connect(lambda: update_ram_bar(self))

        self.timer4 = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer4.timeout.connect(lambda: update_cpu_bar(self))

        #star all the timers
        self.timer.start(1000)
        self.timer2.start(1000)
        self.timer3.start(1000)
        self.timer4.start(1000)

        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
```

As my debugs when there is only 1 timer started the app works fine as soon as there are multiple instances of timers, the app starts to **freeze**.

I want someone to fix the freezing part :/.
Thanks

Comment: How could we fix something we don't know anything about? Please provide a [mre], we cannot just guess answers.

Comment: @musicamante I really don't think you have know a bunch of long code. I just want to start all these timers in [seperate QThreads](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/#:~:text=In%20PyQt%20applications%2C%20the%20main,()%20on%20the%20QApplication%20object.)

Comment: I didn't ask you to post the full code, I specifically asked for a *minimal reproducible example*. Did you read that link? If your program freezes it's because you're probably doing something wrong in those functions (supposedly, you're trying to update something in the UI from another thread, which is forbidden), and if we don't know what happens in those functions, we cannot answer you.

Comment: I told it, maybe I didn't expressed it properly. I mean to say it doesn't crashes the problem is the main thread is doing every single work like running the app, so it is laggy and choppy. Thats why I want to include multiple threads to do seperate works

EDIT: Like the main thread will do no work and I want 4 workers to start those 4 timers

Comment: There is no single and unique way to use threading, and for what we know it's even possible that you don't even need it. We cannot tell you "how to use QThread", nor how to fix the freezing part, because we do not know what you're doing in those functions. So, either you provide a MRE as requested, or your question stays unanswered.

Comment: There are 2 functions that displays the ram usage by updating 2 labels and there are more two functions that gets the same ram usage value from other psutil functions I created and sets the values of 2 progress bars accordingly

Comment: Hello, @PlayZBhai ! I suggest you to please consider using the functions and classes in the `threading` module of standard Python. Besides being very simple and with a clean interface, it has lots of great tutoriais like https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Comment: @HiltonFernandes Using threading alone won't be enough here, as the OP seems to need to update the UI, and direct access to widgets is not allowed from external threads, so using QThread with custom signals is mandatory to avoid unexpected behavior or even fatal crash.

Comment: @PlayZBhai I did not ask you to explain what those function do. We don't (nor can) provide random answers without precise questions, and this is not a tutorial website. So, for the last time, if you want help, you *must* provide a MRE.

Comment: Dear@musicamante, thanks for enlightening me about the intentions of the OP. But unfortunately I have to disagree with you concerning the interoperability between common Python threads and Qt objects. Not only that's feasible, but I recently created a program base precisely in a common thread interfacing with Qt UI objects.

Comment: @HiltonFernandes Switching between threading implementations isn't going to fix basic problems with the OPs code.

Comment: I agree with you, @ekhumoro at 1st, but since the OP is trying to understand the whole idea of multithreading it is better to start off with a simpler and more documented implementation. Don't you think so ?

Comment: @HiltonFernandes No. It's much more common to use `QThread`, and far easier to implement in a basic PyQt/PySide application. This is based on answering thousands of questions on SO in the relevant tags. Questions that require understanding e.g. "the whole area of multithreading" are way off-topic for SO. This is not a tutorial site.

Comment: Dear @ekhumoro, maybe we live in different worlds. In my world, a search in Web will find much more uses of Python's threading, than QThread. I also don't know why you say that here is not a tutorial site: many people come here precisely to look for tutorials.

Comment: @HiltonFernandes This question is specifically about **PyQt** multithreading, and how to use `QThread` with `QTimer` - not threading in general. Tutorial sites are ones where people go to *start learning* programming. SO is not such as site. Please see: [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @HiltonFernandes Seemingly, I tried your way to solve this problem and it worked! Pretty cool way, I don't even have to use QThread either. Just what I wanted, thanks a bunch

Comment: @HiltonFernandes It's not completely impossible, you may try to circumvent it with a custom implementation, but why reinvent the wheel? Signals and slots are fundamental Qt concepts. That is known to work for a simple reason: it's what Qt expects. PyQt QThreads (similarly to python's) are interfaces to the system threading (this was confirmed by the PyQt maintainer): fundamentally speaking, a QThread behaves just like a python one, but with the benefit of signals, so what's the point? There may be exceptions, but in my experience almost any attempt to avoid them was due to poor implementation.